# Avoid mutable variable in for loop

Tags: scala

I have some code like below. But I wish to avoid this mutable variable **flag**.

How can I achieve this?

```
  def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = (x: Int) =>  {
    var flag : Boolean = false
    for(i <- -bound to bound) {
      if(s(i) && f(i) == x){
        flag = true
      }
    }
    flag
  }
```

Comment: I don't know scala at all, but I image you could use a while loop instead of a for loop.  
`while(!s(i) || f(i)!=x)`

Comment: Yes this is a coursera question, and it should be solved with a simple one-liner, not a loop (not that that matters to the question as such).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need this simple test:

```
(-bound to bound) exists {i => s(i) && f(i) == x}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `exists` collection method.  The `exists` method returns `true` if the specified condition is true for at least one element in the collection, and `false` otherwise.

```
def map(s: Set[Int], f: Int => Int): (Int => Boolean) =
  (x: Int) => {
    (-bound to bound).exists(i => s(i) && f(i) == x)
  }
```

Comment: While I really don't want to support giving away solutions, I would at least want to give a pointer towards a better one: The hint about using `exists` is good. If `exists` is implemented as required in the assignment, it calls `foreach`, which already loops from `-bound` to `bound`. TL;DR: Aim at a ~25 char solution which does not require extra iteration but does the trick in the function it passes to `exists`.